# Can we use MTLRenderPipelineState & MTLDepthStencilState in multithread?

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

Can we use MTLRenderPipelineState & MTLDepthStencilState in multithread ? I mean can in thread A assign MTLRenderPipelineState to a RenderCommandEncoder and at the same time from thread B assign also this MTLRenderPipelineState to another RenderCommandEncoder? same for MTLDepthStencilState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Metal state objects are immutable and safe to use across threads.